# Не получается решить с++ задачу

Tags: c++, visual-c++, new

Задана квадратная матрица порядка 7. Вычислить среднее арифметическое
элементов, больших заданного G и лежащих выше главной диагонали.
Программа должна выполнять ввод и вывод матрицы и
дополнительных данных, выполнять необходимые действия и выводить
результаты.

Comment: Почему, мисс Миронова, почему? Во имя чего? Что вы делаете? Зачем, зачем задаёте? Зачем продолжаете задавать вопросы без попыток решения?

Comment: Джонни Кэтсвилл , не согласен, она вопрос и  не задавала.  Я  тут вижу только информацию о том, что нужно делать, но никакого намека на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Подсказка на вопрос как "Вычислить среднее арифметическое элементов, больших заданного G и лежащих выше главной диагонали".

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; ++j) {
        int t = matrix[i][j];
        if (t > G)
            sum += t;
    }
cout  << sum;
```